# What are the dimensions of Discworld?

Tags: discworld

How big is the Discworld Universum?

**Do any dimensions appears in the books?**

For example, if we extrapolate dimensions of Ankh-Morpork to get Disk radius and based on this calculate size of 4 elephants and turtle.

Comment: The Wikipedia states that the moon and the sun of Discworld were 1 mile in diameter in earliest books, and were later stated to be 80 miles in diameter each.

Comment: So in earliest books sun were smaller than Disc. Any quote for this?

Comment: only Wikipedia - I myself have only read _Mort_ and started reading _The_ _Colour_ _of_ _Magic_.

Comment: @janisz The sun is always smaller than, and orbiting, the disk.

Comment: @OrangeDog my bad, misinterpreted thousands comma with decimal dot

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Circumference:** 30,000 miles (ish)

> *"Ten thousands of miles. I just patrol this length.”*
>
> *“That’s a third of the way around the disc!”*
>
> <sub><sup>The Colour of Magic</sup></sub>

As you can see from this top-down map from the Discworld Mappe Atlas, Great A'Tuin isn't dramatically *wider* or *longer* than the Disc's 9,549 mile diameter.

The area of the disk is approx 71,619,724 Miles<sup>2</sup> which is slightly bigger than the pacific ocean.

[image]

Comment: That's about 50000 km (ish) in SI units. Imperials...

Comment: @zommuter - The discworld books were written in English for a British audience. The fact that the odd colonial may have found a copy or two is no good excuse to be going around converting things for them.

Comment: In case anyone wonders, translations also convert the units, but not always to SI. French edition has “Seize mille kilomètres. Moi je patrouille seulement sur une lieue". Which translates back to “Sixteen thousand kilometers. I just patrol one league”.

Comment: @Valorum: I don't recall the British empire extending to discworld... also, the people of Albion should get with the program and start using sane units, not the furlongs-per-forthnight or whatever it is you people have :-)

Comment: How do you know a Discworld mile is the same length as an Imperial mile?

Comment: @JeremyP - Because the Disworld is a "*mirror of worlds*".

Comment: And that means they would use the same units as us because....?

Comment: @JeremyP - If you're desperate to push this point, might I suggest you ask it on the main site...

Comment: Why? I'm just pointing out that we are all making a big assumption when we discuss the dimensions of the Discworld in miles (what kind of miles). It's not even as if there is one canonical length for a mile on Round World.

Comment: @JeremyP - Per my earlier comment, these books were written in English by an English author for a largely English audience. Why would Pratchett make the "Discworld mile" different from the "Imperial mile" that he uses in ordinary conversation daily?

Comment: As per my earlier comment, Discworld is a fictional world in the shape of a flat disc which has analogues of things on Earth not copies. We may assume a Discworld mile is analogous to an Earth mile but it isn't necessarily identical.

Comment: @JeremyP - You should definitely ask that on the main site. I even have an answer ready for you :-) It's slightly too long for a comment, but it comes directly from Mr Pratchett himself.

Comment: "Ten thousands of miles" would imply at least 20000 to me.

Answer (score 1):

Land area calculations for the *Discworld* continents can be found at [Aleph Zero Heroes](https://aleph-zero-heroes.netlify.com/posts/pratchett_discworld/). The page uses Green's Theorem to calculate the areas of the continents from a contour integral around the edge of the maps (the full map appears on [GitHub](https://github.com/mroughan/AlephZeroHeroesData/tree/master/Pratchett)).

- Main continent = 27.6 million sq miles
- XXXX = 1.4  million sq miles
- (total) islands = 1.3 million sq miles

Compared to the total *Discworld* area of 78.5 million sq miles. The calculation presumes a 10,000 mile diameter which is a little different from the calculation above, but an often quoted diameter.

Comment: Could you [edit] in the relevant evidence from the link for how they come up with these numbers? At the moment if the link dies we are just left to take your word for it that this is correct.

Comment: Is that enough detail -- I could put a lot more, but then it might be a bit unwiedly?