# How big is the Circumfence barrier?

Tags: discworld, geography

In *The Colour of Magic*, it is shown there is a net on the edge of the Disc when

> Rincewind and Twoflower almost fall off the edge.

How big is this net? In *The Light Fantastic* on page 13 it mentions ships falling off the world, so I guess it isn’t complete.

**This is not a duplicate.** The Circumfence is one object within the Disc, and I am asking how much of the Disc it covers, rather than just the size of the Disc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the dimensions of Discworld](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138266/what-are-the-dimensions-of-discworld)

Comment: @closevoters This is not a duplicate. The Circumfence is **an object** within the Disc. It is not a misspelling of  "circumference". I am asking how much of the Disc it covers, rather than the circumference of the Disc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tethis (a sea troll) tells us about the Circumfence in The Colour of Magic. It's not small.

> “It could be extended for a couple of miles, if you found enough rocks and things,” said the wizard.
>   **“Ten thousands of miles.** I just patrol this league.”
>   “That’s a third of the way around the Disc!”

You can see it on the authorised [Discworld Mappe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACAiV.jpg). Not quite a third.

[image]

Comment: Oh, forgot that sentence